# "Тем не менее" как наречное выражение

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли оформлено предложение? Интересуют запятые вокруг "тем не менее". Т.к. это наречное выражение, запятых не нужно, обособляем деепричастный оборот, значит, запятая нужна только одна. Правильно ли я рассуждаю?

Объявив еще в конце 2014 года пуск рубля в «свободное плавание», тем не менее Центробанк вынужден поддерживать курс определенным интервенциями, внедрением валютных репо, спотами и другими финансовыми инструментами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пунктуация верна.Это наречное выражение  в значении "всё же".

А вот если Вы послушаетесь совета slava1947, то пунктуация будет факультативна: в середине предложения появляется интонация вводного сочетания или выражения с уступительным значением тем не менее=несмотря на это, тогда возможно обособление.

Comment: "...В данном случае"тем не менее "является союзом, присоединяющим вторую часть сложносочинённого предложения".===
Гм... СЛОЖНОСОЧИНЁННОГО предложения?

Comment: Да, была невнимательна,вернее не увидела из-за плохого зрения, простого предложения, сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 1):

> Объявив еще в конце 2014 года пуск
> рубля в «свободное плавание», **тем не
> менее** Центробанк вынужден поддерживать
> курс определенным интервенциями,
> внедрением валютных репо, спотами и
> другими финансовыми инструментами.

С запятыми всё нормально. А вот **тем не менее** лучше переставить:

Объявив еще в конце 2014 года пуск рубля в «свободное плавание»,  Центробанк  **тем не менее** вынужден поддерживать курс определенным**и** интервенциями...

Comment: Да, "тем не менее" явно не на месте, поскольку "отрезает" Центробанк от начального оборота, по смыслу прямо относящемуся к нему. Ещё неплохо бы заменить "пуск" на "отпускание", а "курс" отнести к рублю (иначе при первом чтении можно подумать на "курс действий Центробанка") - например, "его курс".

Comment: Ничего здесь "тем не менее" не отрезает.Автор вопроса спрашивает о пунктуации именно в этом предложении, а не о его перестройке. Вы же настаиваете на неправильном построении, никаких ошибок в построении нет.

Comment: Людмила: "никаких ошибок в построении нет".
=== ???

Comment: Людмила, начинающееся с противопоставляющего союза "тем не менее" предложение было бы уместным, если бы оно в целом противопоставлялось законченному суждению. Но здесь одни действия (те, что в "предложении") одного и того же "Центробанка" противопоставляются другим (тем, что в деепричастном обороте), причём начало противопоставления предшествует обозначению того, от чего (Центробанка)исходят первые действия . Другой способ исправить эту ошибку (как минимум, стилистическую) - перенести "Центробанк" в самое начало. После этого можно разбираться с запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

В справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ считается частицей (не наречием) или союзом в ССП со значением НО, ОДНАКО.

Следовательно, в приведенном примере это частица, которая придает глаголу уступительный характер. Позицию частицы   хотелось бы изменить, так как она относится к глаголу, а не к Центробанку. Например, так:

Объявив еще в конце 2014 года пуск рубля в «свободное плавание», Центробанк  вЫнужден тем не менее поддерживать курс определенными интервенциями.

При такой структуре предложения мы выделяем логическим ударением слово "вынужден".

Comment: Спасибо всем большое.